# How many parallelograms can be formed when a parallelogram is cut by $2$ sets of $n$ parallel lines?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorics-on-words

A parallelogram is cut by two sets of n parallel lines parallel to the sides of the parallelogram. The number of parallelogram thus formed is..??

I think we can do it by combinatorics.. But I'm not quite sure... Help me out please.

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. For a $1$-dimensional counterpart, if I took a line segment and cut it at $n$ points, how many line segments are thus formed? Most people would answer $n+1$, since a segment with a hole in it does not really seem to qualify as a segment. Also, if you do wish to count these, does the original segment count as one that is "formed" (as it was there from the start)? Please be more explicit about what exactly you wish to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parallelogram $ABCD$:

[image: parallelogram_grid]

A parallelogram is determined by choosing two pairs of opposite sides. If you introduce $n$ lines parallel to the sides of the parallelogram, you have $n + 2$ sides from which to choose the two sides parallel to $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ (including $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ themselves) and also have $n + 2$ sides from which to choose the two sides parallel to $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$ (including $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$ themselves).  Thus, there are $$\binom{n + 2}{2}\binom{n + 2}{2} = \binom{n + 2}{2}^2$$ parallelograms that can be formed from the grid that results when each side of the parallelogram is cut by $n$ lines.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You can squash the parallelogram to make a square, which may as well have the sides vertical and horizonal.  Now cut the square with $n$ vertical lines. How many pieces?  Cut them all with $n$ horizontal lines....  *Draw a picture.*

Comment: Yes... But we have to consider all possible parallelograms... This has to be done through combinatorics... Eg: if I cut the square with two lines, total number of rectangles will be 6... I just want to generalize this 2sets of n parallel lines...

Comment: An affine transformation will take the parallelogram to a square.  If you cut the square with two lines (one each direction) there are $9$ rectangles.  You choose two lines (including the original sides of the square) in each direction.

Answer (score 0):

Each set of parallel consists of $(n+2)$ lines. 
Each parallelogram is formed by using by choosing two lines from each set of lines
Therefore ((selection $2$ lines from each set times $2$))

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).